# Javascript monitor keyboard events causes failure of <input> tag type

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a Javascript code fragment which is used to generate a div

```
<input xxxxx >
<div id="graph">
    <svg> xxxxx </svg>
</div>
```

Within the div, the script monitor the keyboard events to modify the SVG content.

```
function keydown() {
    switch(d3.event.keyCode){
        xxxxxx
    }
}
```

However that causes the failure of `<input>`, I can not type anything in input filed.

Is there any way to address this issue?

Comment: what is the exact code? How is keydown bound?

Answer (score 0):

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/josephj/pen/LBwAj).

#### HTML

```
<h1>SWF and JavaScript Key Event</h1>

<div id="demo"></div>
<ul id="logger"></ul>


</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
#focusable-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000em;
    top: -1000em;
}
#logger {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var attrs = {},
    linkEl,
    params = {};

// Uses SWFObject Renders Player.
// It makes sure you won't have a duplicated ID.
attrs.id = "player"; // Defines player's ID.
params.allowScriptAccess = "always"; // Needed to allow player to call functions.
swfobject.embedSWF(
  "https://www.youtube.com/v/Zhawgd0REhA?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
  "demo", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, attrs
);

// Injects an invisible link as a focus target.
linkEl = document.createElement("a") ;
linkEl.href = "javascript:void(0);";
linkEl.setAttribute("id", "focusable-link");
document.body.appendChild(linkEl);

// Shows all key events.
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerHTML = "keyup event, keyCode = " + e.keyCode;
  document.getElementById("logger").appendChild(item)
    };

    // Always makes sure user can't focus on the SWF.
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (document.getElementById("player") === document.activeElement) {
            document.getElementById("focusable-link").focus();
        }
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }, 100);
```